# Mount data and conf to postgres docker image

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I try to mount specific data folder and the postgresql.conf to the postgres image with `docker-compose`.

Here is my docker-compose.yml sample:

```yaml
postgres:
  image: postgres:11
  volumes:
    - ./data/pg:/var/lib/postgresql/data #here is my specific data folder
    - ./postgresql.conf:/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf #here my custom pg conf
```

But I get the error on the start up:

```
postgres_1  | initdb: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty
postgres_1  | If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
postgres_1  | the directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" or run initdb
postgres_1  | with an argument other than "/var/lib/postgresql/data".
```

I guess that my second volume (`/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf`) conflicts with the first (`/var/lib/postgresql/data`) - because if I comment the second - it will work ok. But I have no idea how to do stuff properly, I want to be able to mount both (the data and the conf) simultaneously

Comment: What about following the [official image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) ? Search for "Database Configuration" on that page and pay attention to the bind mount target out of the data dir as well as the custom option `-c` to start postgres.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need to copy postgresql.conf to a different location and then instruct postgres to use the conf file from the new location.

Something like this:

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
    - ./data/pg:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    - ./postgresql.conf:/etc/postgres/my.conf
    command: "-c 'config_file=/etc/postgres/my.conf'"
```